# Synonym of "walk" for this specific context

Tags: synonyms

I was wondering if there is a more precise verb to express "walk" for a pedestrian who is moving around a city, someone who is not "enjoying a nice walk with her/his partner" or "wandering around" but moving with a clear purpose towards a direction. Something like "cruising" with your car when you are commuting to work.

**Example sentence**: *you can see a difference in the navigation pattern of a subject who is simply enjoying social life outdoors from one that is walking as a mean of transportation to get from point A to point B; the first is slow and erratic, the second is fast and traces a neat trajectory*

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence?

Comment: "He *headed* straight to work."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I found a multitude of words for "leisurely walk", I was a little taken aback upon searching for a word for "walking with a clear purpose". However, upon eliminating all the synonyms of "walk" which mean "to walk leisurely", I was left with the following list of words which could be used for your purpose (in decreasing order of relevance):

1. March: [to move in a direct purposeful manner](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/march)
2. Tread: [to walk or proceed along](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tread)
3. Traipse: [to go on foot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/traipse)
4. Perambulate: [to walk or travel through or round a place](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/perambulate)
5. Stride: [to move over or along with or as if with long measured steps](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stride)
6. Hike: [a long walk or walking tour](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hike)

(I have linked the meanings to point to their sources. )

Comment: Please provide a comment while downvoting so that the answer can be improved.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I would say that some of them are precisely synonyms of wandering around (perambulate, traipse), but I appreciate the effort to make the list

Comment: maybe March is the one resembling the most, sounds a little bit odd for what i want to convey but I will take this one

Comment: I agree with you that using even "march" here is not very becoming ( although the least inappropriate). If you don't have to restrict yourself to a word, you can even use a phrase like "going about their business" etc.

Comment: "Stride" seems to me the best, and only real example worth considering from that list. Another might be "pace" - but that can imply running.